# Undo or override Apache "Require" directives

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4, shibboleth

Suppose in our core Apache 2.4 config, we have

```
<Directory "/">
    AuthType foo
    Require bar
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
</Directory>
```

But... `Require foo` is actually too permissive for one particular directory.

We can add a `.htaccess` file to a subdirectory, but we cannot be *more* restrictive than `Require foo` because that's already been applied.

Is there a way to un-apply it? For the `.htaccess` file to say "please disregard Require directives given earlier and let me start again from scratch"?

In my specific situation I have `AuthType shibboleth` with `Require shibboleth` (which merely enables Shibboleth without limiting access to any particular criteria), so there is perhaps a Shibboleth-specific answer here as well.